# Cannot retrieve needed files for okteto on Windows behind proxy

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, proxy, okteto

I'm trying to deploy okteto environment on Visual Studio Code to use Remote Development on Kubernetes.

Following the official steps (https://okteto.com/blog/remote-kubernetes-development/), I executed "Okteto: up" and selected manifest(vscode-remote-go/okteto.yml), but got this error:

```
Installing dependencies...  
 x  couldn't download syncthing, please try again
```

By changing the log level, I also got these logs:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\okteto.exe up -f 'c:\Workspace\...my_project...\vscode-remote-go\okteto.yml' --remote '22100' --loglevel=debug
time="2021-09-13T14:09:32+09:00" level=info msg="starting up command"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:32+09:00" level=info msg="failed to get latest version from github: fail to get releases from github: Get \"https://api.github.com/repos/okteto/okteto/releases?per_page=5\": dial tcp: lookup api.github.com: no such host"
Installing dependencies...
time="2021-09-13T14:09:32+09:00" level=info msg="installing syncthing for windows/amd64"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:32+09:00" level=info msg="failed to download syncthing, retrying: failed to download syncthing from https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip: Get \"https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip\": dial tcp: lookup github.com: no such host"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:33+09:00" level=info msg="installing syncthing for windows/amd64"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:33+09:00" level=info msg="failed to download syncthing, retrying: failed to download syncthing from https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip: Get \"https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip\": dial tcp: lookup github.com: no such host"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:34+09:00" level=info msg="installing syncthing for windows/amd64"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:34+09:00" level=info msg="failed to upgrade syncthing: failed to download syncthing from https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip: Get \"https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip\": dial tcp: lookup github.com: no such host"
time="2021-09-13T14:09:34+09:00" level=info msg="couldn't download syncthing, please try again"
 x  couldn't download syncthing, please try again
```

This environment is behind my corporate proxy, and okteto.exe may not use Windows proxy setting. When I directly enter the URL (https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/releases/download/v1.10.0/syncthing-windows-amd64-v1.10.0.zip) it can be downloaded using proxy.

Is it possible to use okteto behind proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a proxy is not currently supported in the Okteto. We're looking into it though.

For now, a workaround is to manually download the syncthing binary and save it as`%HOME%\.okteto\syncthing.exe`